# Stored procedure lock while executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which executes for 10 seconds.

Is it possible that while one user executes this procedure, the procedure could be locked for other users?

If another user executes the procedure concurrently I would like it to print `'Wait it's executing'` or something else informative.

Comment: Everything (almost) is possible but, what would be a good reason to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203038/prevent-a-stored-procedure-from-being-executed-twice-at-the-same-time

Comment: Umm, what does have a compilation to do with the execution time or locking? Also, what is the question?

Comment: @GeoVIP, if you take the time to make your questions easy to read, perople are more likely to take the time to read, and answer them. In this case, your question is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1203070/659190

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear if you want to avoid serialisation or demand it.

Stored procedures are not generally serial so you can run more than one instance at once.  Theoretically you could block concurrent execution by doing an update to a known row for the duration but most times people are actively seeking to avoid serialisation not incur it.

What are you trying to do?